# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')'

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

How can I add a condition inside a php array?

Here is the array

```
$content['custom_fields'] = array(
    array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_focuskw", "value" => $_POST["title"] ),
    array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_metadesc", "value" => $_POST["titleenfa"] ),
    array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_metakeywords", "value" => $_POST["metakey"] ),
    if($_POST["link128"]){
        array( "key" => "_link128", "value" => "field_54b398292c295" ),
        array( "key" => "link128", "value" => $_POST["link128"] ),
    }
    if($_POST["link256"]){
        array( "key" => "_link256", "value" => "field_54b398092c294" ),
        array( "key" => "link256", "value" => $_POST["link256"] ),
    }
    if($_POST["link320"]){          
        array( "key" => "_link320", "value" => "field_54b3965495d27" ),
        array( "key" => "link320", "value" => $_POST["link320"] ),
    }
    array( "key" => "country", "value" => "USA" )
);
```

But I get the PHP Parse error, why I can add a condition inside the array, what's happen??:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')'

Comment: You forgot closing ")" right before first T_IF statement.
Check this. You cannot include this statement inside array declaration

Comment: either conditionally add entries later, or filter out (delete) the ones you don't need.

Comment: As @Rizier123 stated, you can use `array_push` to add the *if* values later to your array.

Comment: as a sidenote: `array`s store key-value *mappings*, why do you store a key+value *pair* (as value) in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone

```
        $content['custom_fields'] = array(
        array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_focuskw", "value" => $_POST["title"] ),
        array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_metadesc", "value" => $_POST["titleenfa"] ),
        array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_metakeywords", "value" => $_POST["metakey"] )
        );
        if($_POST["link128"]){
            array_push($content['custom_fields'], array( "key" => "_link128", "value" => "field_54b398292c295" ) );
            array_push($content['custom_fields'], array( "key" => "link128", "value" => $_POST["link128"] ) );
        }       
        if($_POST["link256"]){
            array_push($content['custom_fields'], array( "key" => "_link256", "value" => "field_54b398092c294" ) );
            array_push($content['custom_fields'], array( "key" => "link256", "value" => $_POST["link256"] ) );
        }   
        if($_POST["link320"]){
            array_push($content['custom_fields'], array( "key" => "_link320", "value" => "field_54b3965495d27" ) );
            array_push($content['custom_fields'], array( "key" => "link320", "value" => $_POST["link320"] ) );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't write a if statement in a array declaration, but what you could do is to use a [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) operator like this:

(Here you would have either way a entry)

```
array( "key" => "link128", "value" => (!empty($_POST["link128"])?$_POST["link128"]:"") )
```

OR you can use [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) like this:

Where it push's one or more elements to the end of your array

```
if($_POST["link128"])
    array_push($array, $_POST["link128"]);
```

Comment: this will unconditionally add an entry. I doubt that's what he needs.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Added another possible solution, also he just can check if it is empty when he uses it

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your array code like following.....

```
$custom_array = array(
    array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_focuskw", "value" => $_POST["title"] ),
    array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_metadesc", "value" => $_POST["titleenfa"] ),
    array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_metakeywords", "value" => $_POST["metakey"]     
)); 
if($_POST["link128"]){
   $custom_array = array_merge($custom_array,array(
        array( "key" => "_link128", "value" => "field_54b398292c295" ),
        array( "key" => "link128", "value" => $_POST["link128"] ),
     ));
}
if($_POST["link256"]){
   $custom_array = array_merge($custom_array,array(
        array( "key" => "_link256", "value" => "field_54b398092c294" ),
        array( "key" => "link256", "value" => $_POST["link256"] ),
   ));
 }
if($_POST["link320"]){
   $custom_array = array_merge($custom_array,array(
       array( "key" => "_link320", "value" => "field_54b3965495d27" ),
        array( "key" => "link320", "value" => $_POST["link320"] ),
    ));
```

}

```
//And finally
$content['custom_fields'] = array_merge($custom_array,array(
   array( "key" => "country", "value" => "USA" )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also write that as:

```
$x = array();

$x[] = array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_focuskw", "value" => $_POST["title"] );
$x[] = array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_metadesc", "value" => $_POST["titleenfa"] );
$x[] = array( "key" => "_yoast_wpseo_metakeywords", "value" => $_POST["metakey"] );

if($_POST["link128"]){
    $x[] = array( "key" => "_link128", "value" => "field_54b398292c295" );
    $x[] = array( "key" => "link128", "value" => $_POST["link128"] );
}
if($_POST["link256"]){
    $x[] = array( "key" => "_link256", "value" => "field_54b398092c294" );
    $x[] = array( "key" => "link256", "value" => $_POST["link256"] );
}
if($_POST["link320"]){          
    $x[] = array( "key" => "_link320", "value" => "field_54b3965495d27" );
    $x[] = array( "key" => "link320", "value" => $_POST["link320"] );
}

$x[] = array( "key" => "country", "value" => "USA" )

$content['custom_fields'] = $x;
```

The `$x[] = $y` means "push `$y` onto the end of the array `$x`."